# Raycast does not collect collision with object Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, 360-virtual-reality

I am making a 360 video and need to use raycast to select options for a menu. I have drawn the ray cast and it seems to be okay. However, no detection is happening. The buttons are in the world view and have a mesh collider and 'is trigger' is enabled.

Below is the script attached to the main camera:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

public class VrEyeRaycaster : MonoBehaviour {
    public string objectCollided;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    //create the ray to cast forward
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 origin = transform.position;
    Vector3 direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)*20;
    Ray ray = new Ray(origin, direction);
    Debug.DrawRay(origin, direction, Color.green);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
    {
        objectCollided = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
        print(objectCollided);
    }
    else
    {
        string s = "Nothing hit by RayCaster";
        print(s);
    }
}
```

}

I have tried putting the camera and its container into the world canvas but it hasn't worked either. Any ideas where I may be going wrong??? I can't actually see if the ray is penatrating the button because I can only see the ray in scene window and can only see the buttons in the game window.

Comment: You may want to get the [VR Samples project](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/?&_ga=2.147556983.1321543295.1509656086-1563649833.1499705575#!/content/51519) then read [this guide](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/interaction-vr?playlist=22946) and look at the VREyeRaycaster, VRInput, and VRInteractiveItem scripts. you also may want to read the next chapter [User Interfaces for VR](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/user-interfaces-vr?playlist=22946) as you are making UI stuff.

Comment: `isTrigger` is for volumes that *triggers* when an object is inside them, rather than being *collided* against.  `queryTriggerInteraction  Specifies whether this [raycast] query should hit Triggers.`

Comment: Draco, you mean he should set the queryTriggerInteraction inside the Physics.Raycast parameters, correct?